# Is a Temp Table the best solution?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, temp-tables

I'm building a stored proc that pulls a lot of different data from several different tables, and I need a way to pull sales information from a sales table and then perform various summations on that sales data. In the example below I accomplish this using a temp table, but someone suggested there's probably a better way. Is there a more efficient way to accomplish what I'm doing here?

```
 SELECT * INTO #TempSales FROM [Sales] WHERE ClientId = @ClientId
    SELECT 
        [Customer].[CustomerID],
        [Customer].[AccountBalAmountOpen],
        [Customer].[AccountAgeAmountDays0],
        [Customer].[AccountAgeAmountDays30],
        [Customer].[AccountAgeAmountDays60],
        [Customer].[AccountAgeAmountDays90],
        [Customer].[AccountAgeAmountDaysOver90],
        (SELECT SUM(SalesAmount) FROM #TempSales WHERE CustomerId = [Customer].[CustomerID] AND Origin = 385) AS ServiceLifeTimeSales,
        (SELECT SUM(SalesAmount) FROM #TempSales WHERE CustomerId = [Customer].[CustomerID] AND Origin = 385 AND MONTH(SaleDate) = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND YEAR(SaleDate) = YEAR(GETDATE())) AS ServiceMonthToDateSales,
        (SELECT SUM(SalesAmount) FROM #TempSales WHERE CustomerId = [Customer].[CustomerID] AND Origin = 385 AND YEAR(SaleDate) = YEAR(GETDATE())) AS ServiceYearToDateSales,
        (SELECT SUM(SalesAmount) FROM #TempSales WHERE CustomerId = [Customer].[CustomerID] AND Origin = 385 AND YEAR(SaleDate) = (YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1)) AS ServicePreviousYearSales,
    (SELECT SUM(SalesAmount) FROM #TempSales WHERE CustomerId = [Customer].[CustomerID] AND Origin = 460) AS PartsLifeTimeSales,
        (SELECT SUM(SalesAmount) FROM #TempSales WHERE CustomerId = [Customer].[CustomerID] AND Origin = 460 AND MONTH(SaleDate) = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND YEAR(SaleDate) = YEAR(GETDATE())) AS PartsMonthToDateSales,
        (SELECT SUM(SalesAmount) FROM #TempSales WHERE CustomerId = [Customer].[CustomerID] AND Origin = 460 AND YEAR(SaleDate) = YEAR(GETDATE())) AS PartsYearToDateSales,
        (SELECT SUM(SalesAmount) FROM #TempSales WHERE CustomerId = [Customer].[CustomerID] AND Origin = 460 AND YEAR(SaleDate) = (YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1)) AS PartsPreviousYearSales,
        [Orders].[CustomerId] AS ParentCustomerId,
        [Orders].[OrderId],
        [Orders].[OrderStatus],
        [Orders].[UnitId],
        [Orders].[FleetId],
        [Orders].[CreatedDate] AS OrderCreatedDate,
        [Orders].[OrderType],
        [OrderParts].[OrderId] AS ParentOrderId,
        [OrderParts].[PartId],
        [OrderParts].[PartDescription],
        [OrderParts].[QuantityShip],
        [OrderParts].[QuantityBackOrder],
        [OrderParts].[CreatedDate] AS PartCreatedDate
      FROM [Customer]
      LEFT JOIN [Orders]
      ON [Orders].[CustomerId] = [Customer].[CustomerID]
      LEFT JOIN [OrderParts]
      ON [OrderParts].[OrderId] = [Orders].[OrderId]
      WHERE [Customer].[ClientID] = @ClientId
DROP TABLE #TempSales
```

Comment: Procedural code like stored procedures is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Subqueries in select string is rarely the best way to proceed

Comment: It seems like you can do all of the processing that you need in one pass anyway. The first select filters on a single clientid. The second select does everything else. Why not just add the clientid filter to your second select and do it in one query? Too slow? do some performance tuning (i.e. add indexes etc.)

Comment: What's the difference in this system between a Sale and an Order? Between a Client and a Customer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although temporary tables can be useful to store intermediate results of complex queries that are going to be reused in other queries, I don't think that you need it for your calculations as you are creating the temporary table as this:

```
SELECT * INTO #TempSales FROM [Sales] WHERE ClientId = @ClientId
```

You are not joining the table with anything nor making calculations or using aggregate functions, so if the table is properly indexed (at least `ClientId`, `CustomerId`, `Origin` and `SalesDate`), your query should perform fine or even faster, because tables created using `SELECT INTO` doesn't have any index unless you manually add them.

But probably you are experiencing a speed improvement using the temporary table because you have conditions like this:

```
AND YEAR(SaleDate) = YEAR(GETDATE())
AND MONTH(SaleDate) = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND YEAR(SaleDate) = YEAR(GETDATE())
```

which [make the query non-sargable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/799584/49934) as you are enclosing the filter column in a function. Due to this the query optimizer can't properly use any existing index on `SaleDate`, and since the temporal table has fewer rows it can take less time perform a full scan on it than on the `Sales` table.

You can fix that using a condition that doesn't apply any function to the filter column (although you can use functions on constant values):

```
declare @thisYearStart as datetime, @nextYearStart as datetime,
  @thisMonthStart as datetime, @nextMonthStart as datetime

set @thisYearStart=DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),1,1)
set @nextYearStart=DATEADD(year,1,@thisYearStart)
set @thisMonthStart=DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),MONTH(GETDATE()),1)
set @nextMonthStart=DATEADD(month,1,@thisMonthStart)
```

or if you are using a version of SQL older than SQL Server 2012:

```
set @thisYearStart=CAST(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) as char(4))+'0101' AS datetime) -- ISO format
set @nextYearStart=DATEADD(year,1,@thisYearStart)
set @thisMonthStart=DATEADD(month,MONTH(GETDATE())-1,@thisYearStart)
set @nextMonthStart=DATEADD(month,1,@thisMonthStart)
```

and then just use:

```
AND SaleDate>=@thisYearStart AND SaleDate<@nextYearStart
AND SaleDate>=@thisMonthStart AND SaleDate<@nextMonthStart
```

Note that you don't need to use the variables, you could use the `DATEFROMPARTS(...)` directly on the `WHERE` condition but since you are already creating a stored procedure using them they will make the query more readable.